# number of permutation in a boolean expression containing only ANDs and ORs

Tags: permutations, boolean-algebra

I need to find the number of permutations of some expression which contains only conjunctions and disjunctions e.g.:
$$
e = x_1x_2  \vee x_3x_4
$$
where $x_1x_2$ and $x_3x_4$ are *boolean summands*, interpreted as $x_1 \wedge x_2$, $x_3 \wedge x_4$. The variables $x_1, x_2, \ldots x_4$ are the *boolean factors*.

I need to know the number of permutations, that such an expression can have, i.e.:

```
x1x2 V x3x4
x2x1 V x3x4
x1x2 V x4x3
...
x3x4 V x1x2
...
```

According to my calculations, my formula for the number of permutations for this type of boolean expressions is:

$$
n!(\prod_{i \in n} m_i!)
$$

where $n$ is the number of boolean *summands*, and $m$ the number of boolean *factors* (in a boolean summand).
I would appreciate it a lot, if you could tell me if this formula is correct, and if not, show a correct one.

thanks in advance!

Comment: It seems right.

Comment: You need to fix typo: x4∧x4

Comment: @StainlessSteelRat: Thats a good catch. Fixed it :). Thnx

Comment: I would of fixed it, but only 1 character.